# Why do I need to specify a "\n" in printf unlike in print?

Tags: awk, printf, newline

I am reading an ebook called "The AWK programming language" and I am currently on chapter 1.3 and observed how `print` and `printf` works.

Let's say I am going to print out the contents of `emp.data` in the form of `"total pay of [name] [total pay]"`.

The data in `emp.data` is:

```
Beth    4.00    0
Dan     3.75    0
Kathy   4.00    10
Mark    5.00    20
Mary    5.50    22
Susie   4.25    18
```

When I use `print` in the terminal, I only need to type:

```
$ awk '{ print "total pay of", $s1, $s2 * $s3 }' emp.data
```

But when I use the `printf` in the terminal, I also need to specifiy `\n` like so:

```
$ awk '{ printf("total pay for %s $%.2f\n", $1, $2 * $3) }' emp.data
```

They output the same results but why do I need to specify `\n` in the end of the string to print a newline in `printf` unlike in `print`?

Comment: Maybe print was designed to always print a line unlike printf that allows better output control.

Comment: By default `printf` needs `\n` to print the next line in newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the GNU AWK User's Guide:

> The printf statement does not automatically append a newline to its output. It outputs only what the format string specifies. So if a newline is needed, you must include one in the format string. The output separator variables OFS and ORS have no effect on printf statements.

Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html#Basic-Printf

Answer (score 0):

These predefined methods are designed for different puprposes.
So there could be a scneario where you don't want to use newline after every output, thats where you can use `printf` and else use `print`.
As simple as that.